# Why llvm-build doesn't see custom backend?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, cmake, llvm

I'm trying to write a custom backend for LLVM. I copied a `llvm/lib/Target/AVR` folder to `llvm/lib/Target/Abc` (it's my backend). Then I replaced all `AVR` with `Abc` and `avr` with `abc` in file names and in file contents. Here is `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(LLVM_TARGET_DEFINITIONS Abc.td)

tablegen(LLVM AbcGenRegisterInfo.inc -gen-register-info)
tablegen(LLVM AbcGenInstrInfo.inc -gen-instr-info)
tablegen(LLVM AbcGenCallingConv.inc -gen-callingconv)
tablegen(LLVM AbcGenSubtargetInfo.inc -gen-subtarget)
add_public_tablegen_target(AbcCommonTableGen)

add_llvm_target(AbcCodeGen
  AbcInstrInfo.cpp
  AbcRegisterInfo.cpp
  AbcTargetMachine.cpp
  AbcTargetObjectFile.cpp
)

add_dependencies(LLVMAbcCodeGen intrinsincs_gen)

add_subdirectory(MCTargetDesc)
add_subdirectory(TargetInfo)
```

I tryed to add `Abd` to `LLVM_ALL_TARGETS` variable in `llvm/CMakeLists.txt`, but when I try to run `cmake`, the following error is displayed:

```
llvm-build: error: invalid target to enable: 'Abc' not in project
```

I also tryed to remove `Abc` from `llvm/CMakeLists.txt` and run `cmake` with `-DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=Abc`, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't add `Abc` to `subdirectories` in `llvm/lib/Target/LLVMBuild.txt`.